# AngularJS: directive start only after scope model update

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have one question:

in my app i get from the server some data, and i use this color picker:

http://jsfiddle.net/LAJCa/190/

and i need to run this colorpicker only after my controller get from the server some data...

i try it so (in directive i have):

```
        scope.$watch('renderColor', function(newValue) {
          if (newValue){
            input.spectrum(options);
          }
        });
```

and in controller i have:

```
 $scope.colorHex = '#ffffff';

 myService.getColor().then(function(response) {
   $scope.colorHex = response.ColorHex;
   $scope.renderColor = true;
 });
```

but it still didn't run with the new `scope.colorHex` value, it take '#ffffff'...

only if i wrap this into timeout (for example in 1 second) - this works, but it is a bad practice...

which way is the best to run and update my directive, after i fetch some data from the server?

`$scope.colorHex` - this value didn't want to change...

Comment: It's because when you call the server it's asynchronous. You have to work with a promise like your then in your example. Here he puts the colorHex value only after the server response. So you have to do the same for your directive. Currently your value is change after the view, so the view use #fffff

Comment: Yes as @Apédémak said you need to first request data from server (either using promise or just make plain $http call) and then on "then" callback when your data is ready do whatever you need to do with your color picker. If your view is dependent on this data display some loader and hide it when your data is initialized

Comment: @Glogo what you mean? where to put this callback?

Comment: @Glogo `myService.getColor().then(function(response) {
   $scope.colorHex = response.ColorHex;` - i'm setting color only after data is recieved

Comment: @Apédémak i need more details...

Comment: Your variable colorHex is up to date, it's not the problem. But the view use this variable to init your color picker, before this variable is correlty set by the server. I don't really know how you set the value of your color picker, but it have to be done only on the `then`.

Comment: @Apédémak but it is set in then block

Comment: Your variable is. Not your view. As it seems, your view is load before the execution of the `then`